# Remove .mp4 video top and bottom black bars using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I'm new to ffmpeg and I have heard that it has a filter for black. I want to remove black bars on top and bottom of the video so the video will be cropped to the remaining video without black bars. Thanks:)

Comment: Windows? Install WinFF. It will allow you to type in the values you want to crop through a GUI...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

## FFmpeg cropdetect and crop filters

### 1. Get crop parameters

[cropdetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect) can be used to provide the parameters for the [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) filter. In this example the first 90 seconds is skipped and 10 frames are processed:

```
$ ffmpeg -ss 90 -i input.mp4 -vframes 10 -vf cropdetect -f null -
...
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x220cdc0] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:215 t:0.215000 crop=1280:720:0:0
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x220cdc0] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:257 t:0.257000 crop=1280:720:0:0
[Parsed_cropdetect_0 @ 0x220cdc0] x1:0 x2:1279 y1:0 y2:719 w:1280 h:720 x:0 y:0 pts:299 t:0.299000 crop=1280:720:0:0
```

At the end of each line, you can see it says `crop=1280:720:0:0`. So according to cropdetect we can use `crop=1280:720:0:0`.

### 2. Preview with `ffplay`

```
$ ffplay -vf crop=1280:720:0:0 input.mp4
```

### 3. Re-encode using the crop filter

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf crop=1280:720:0:0 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

In this example the audio is just [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxed) since you probably don't need to re-encode it.

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg and H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

---

## Crop during playback

As you've seen above with the `ffplay` example some players allow you to crop upon playback. This has the advantage of:

- Instant gratification; no need to re-encode
- The quality is preserved

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to ffmpeg and I do not understand the part to remove black bars on top and bottom and resize video to the remaining size without black bars.

Comment: Is there an automating way to remove black bars or I have to use manually crop values always?

Comment: @rexhin When you run cropdetect it will dump a bunch of info in the console output as shown above. It literally gives you the actual crop parameters that you need to use. You can automate it via scripting.

Comment: Wow awesome it worked. But where did we put the filter for black? Also what are the other two params in crop=1280:720:0:24

Comment: It has removed the top black bar but has left a small black bar at bottom. Why did this happen?

Comment: @rexhin Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by, "where did we put the filter for black?". See the [crop documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) to see what each parameter means. If cropdetect did not supply the correct values, then you will have to adjust it ([see docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect)), or just use crop "manually".

Comment: Thank you very much :) I am more clear now aurodetect works just fine.

Comment: cropdetect command does not work, returns "At least one output file must be specified"

Comment: @Andy Without your command and console output I can't come up with any suggestions.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I guess the problem is in ffmpeg for mac. All tools for mac have some quirks.

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

@LordNeckbeard 's answer is great.  I would recommend it in most cases.

ffplay worked great and previewed well, but the version of ffmpeg I was using struggled with the audio from this video I was using.

```
st:1 error, non monotone timestamps
```

I ended up having trouble with the proposed answer both with `-c:a` not being supported with the version I was running and with a problem with bitrate conversion with the video I was using.

Note: `-c:a` can be replaced with: `-acodec`

The easiest alternative free solution I found was to use handbrake.

It's autocrop removed the black bars without much trouble.

Hope that helps.